# Pyspark : How to pick the values till last from the first occurrence in an array based on the matching values in another column

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an dataframe where I need to search a value present in one column i.e., StringType in another column i.e., ArrayType but I want to pick the values from the second column till last value in array from the first occurences of the first column.

Explained below with examples :

Input DF is below :

```
Employee_Name|Employee_ID|Mapped_Project_ID
Name1|E101|[E101, E102, E103]
Name2|E102|[E101, E102, E103]
Name3|E103|[E101, E102, E103, E104, E105]
```

Output DF Should look like as below:

```
Employee_Name|Employee_ID|Mapped_Project_ID
Name1|E101|[E101, E102, E103]
Name2|E102|[E102, E103]
Name3|E103|[E103, E104, E105]
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Spark 2.4 you can use `array_position` and `slice` functions:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f    
from pyspark.sql.functions import array_position
from pyspark.sql.functions import slice

df = spark.createDataFrame([(["c", "b", "a","e","f"],'a')], ['arraydata','item'])

df.select(df.arraydata, f.expr("slice(arraydata,array_position(arraydata, item),size(arraydata))").alias("res")).show()

+---------------+---------+
|      arraydata|      res|
+---------------+---------+
|[c, b, a, e, f]|[a, e, f]|
+---------------+---------+
```

Please just translate this into your df colnames. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @mrjoseph for the solution, but unfortunately I am using Spark 2.3 in my project.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want i think, i have implemented it on dummy data also:

```
import pyspark.sql.types as T
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([['E101',["E101", "E102", "E103", "E104", "E105"]]],["eid", "mapped_eid"])
df.persist()
df.show(truncate = False)

+----+------------------------------+
|eid |mapped_eid                    |
+----+------------------------------+
|E101|[E101, E102, E103, E104, E105]|
+----+------------------------------+

@F.udf(returnType=T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))
def find_element(element,temp_list):
    count = 0
    res = []
    for i in range(len(temp_list)):
        if (count == 0) and (temp_list[i] != element):
            count = 1
            res.append(temp_list[i]) 
        elif count == 1:
            res.append(temp_list[i]) 
    return res

df.withColumn(
    "res_col",
    find_element(F.col("eid"), F.col("mapped_eid"))
).show(truncate = False)

+----+------------------------------+------------------------+
|eid |mapped_eid                    |res_col                 |
+----+------------------------------+------------------------+
|E101|[E101, E102, E103, E104, E105]|[E102, E103, E104, E105]|
+----+------------------------------+------------------------+
```

let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Can we avoid using UDF. I want to work without using UDF

Comment: No we cant without using UDF that won't be the optimum approach the only other option is by splitting the array won't recommend it

Comment: Using udfs could be avoided by using new functions (as of Spark 2.4): slice and array_position: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=substring#pyspark.sql.functions.slice