# pick from first occurrences till last values in array column in pyspark df

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have problem in which is have to search for first occurrence of "Employee_ID" in "Mapped_Project_ID", Need to pick the values in the array till last value from the first matching occurrences

I have one dataframe like below :

```
Employee_Name|Employee_ID|Mapped_Project_ID
Name1|E101|[E101, E102, E103]
Name2|E102|[E101, E102, E103]
Name3|E103|[E101, E102, E103, E104, E105]
```

I want to have output df like below:

```
Employee_Name|Employee_ID|Mapped_Project_ID
Name1|E101|[E101, E102, E103]
Name2|E102|[E102, E103]
Name3|E103|[E103, E104, E105]
```

Not sure, How to achieve this.

Can someone provide an help on this or logic to handle this in spark without need of any UDFs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyspark : How to pick the values till last from the first occurrence in an array based on the matching values in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56358413/pyspark-how-to-pick-the-values-till-last-from-the-first-occurrence-in-an-array)

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the schema of your DataFrame (`df.printSchema()`).

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your dataframe you can use spark 2.4's higher order array function (see https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/apache-spark-2.4-functions.html) to filter out any values within the array that are lower than the value in the Employee_ID column like so:

```
myDataframe
  .selectExpr(
    "Employee_Name", 
    "Employee_ID", 
    "filter(Mapped_Project_ID, x -> x >= Employee_ID) as Mapped_Project_ID"
  );
```

Comment: I am working with spark 2.3 and these are string values which I want to pick from exact matching.

Comment: @DeepanKarSehdev - Welcome to SO. What is type of Mapped_Project_ID column is it "String" or "Array"?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome @Shan . Yes it is array type. Sorry for late reply :-(